# How to authorize Google API inside of Docker

Tags: docker, google-bigquery, google-api

I am running an application inside of Docker that requires me to leverage **google-bigquery**. When I run it outside of Docker, I just have to go to the link below (redacted) and authorize. However, the link doesn't work when I copy-paste it from the Docker terminal. I have tried port mapping as well and no luck either.

**Code:**

```
credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
    key_path, scopes=["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform"],
)
# Make clients.
client = bigquery.Client(credentials=credentials, project=credentials.project_id,)
```

**Response:**
`requests_oauthlib.oauth2_session - DEBUG - Generated new state`
`Please visit this URL to authorize this application:`

Answer (score 0):

Please see the available solutions [on this page](https://cloud.google.com/artifact-registry/docs/docker/authentication#json-key), it's constantly updated.

- gcloud credential helper
- Standalone Docker credential helper
- Access token
- Service account key

In short you need to use a [service account key](https://cloud.google.com/artifact-registry/docs/docker/authentication#json-key) file. Make sure you either use a Secret Manager, or you just issue a service account key file for the purpose of the Docker image.

You need to place the service account key file into the Docker container either at build or runtime.

Comment: I have a service account key. It's just that when I click that link in the Response above, it takes me to **This page isn't working** webpage. This may not be a Docker issue because I am getting it on the local machine now. It usually works the first time, but not subsequent times.

Comment: There should be no link, if you have a link it means a PERSON needs to authorize something as OAuth. A service account key file can be added into the code, and works properly. Revisit your code as you may be using it wrong.

Comment: Interesting. I usually run in it in a Jupyter notebook that takes me to the site automatically and authenticates (if I'm signed in) but this is from a Docker container. Very strange. Thank you.